# What can l use to make the container is not responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am developing the bank I webpage that has container and I have implemented the bootstrap so it can be responsive and all the page become responsive except my container! I have tried every thing but l don’t know what is the problem?

```css
form {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 17% auto;
}

.signup {
  padding: 0px 25px 25px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0px 4px 20px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.33);
}
```

```html
<form action="insert_2.php" method="post" class="needs-validation" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="responsive" novalidate>
  <body style="background-image: url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5a5335f3f43b55247f4b4c5c/1591451356938-K6IBQ2JD9G881GECIOIQ/Untitled+design-5.png');  background-attachment: fixed; background-size: 100%;">
    <div class="signup container">
      <div class="header"></div>
```

Comment: Please start with valid  HTML

Comment: If you're using bootstrap to get it to be responsive, why are you hard coding widths for elements instead of using the bootstrap grid system?

Answer (score -1):

Why your body tag is after form?

Change your HTML structure like this and try again:

```
<body style="background-image: url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5a5335f3f43b55247f4b4c5c/1591451356938-K6IBQ2JD9G881GECIOIQ/Untitled+design-5.png');  background-attachment: fixed; background-size: 100%;">
  <form action="insert_2.php" method="post" class="needs-validation" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="responsive" novalidate>
    <div class="signup">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="header"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you need to add max-width: 100%